# .net Micro Framework consuming web service wsdl error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-micro-framework

Possible bug in either VS2010 SP1 or .netMF 4.1.

I have a web service that was coded in VS2008 and a .netMicro app that consumes it. Without going into too much detail about how to get .netMF to consume a web service I want to point out the issue.

A web service WSDL is built on the fly by VS. Its an easy process. If you view the Service Description (sample below)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
 <wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
                xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" 
                xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
                xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/"
                **xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"** 
                xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" 
                xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"  
                xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
```

only one definition in this example is missing the slash at the end.

Both VS 2008 and VS 2010 build the WSDL in this manner, but the .netMF will error when coding in VS2010.

The process to generate the files in netMF error on this issue.

Has anyone encountered this? Adding the slash solves the problem, but what might it effect by adding the slash.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this in netmf 4.2 with the same result?

If using a full framework (non-netmf) app to try to consume the wsdl works, you can check/post on the official repository/issue tracker :http://netmf.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic and/or get further response at [the support forum](http://www.netmf.com/forum/default.aspx?g=topics&f=6).

I wouldn't advise to add the slash to "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" address since the url with the '/' appended does not return the same page (gives 404 error).

You can visit [this page](http://atmanes.blogspot.ca/2006/07/short-explanation-of-xml-namespaces.html) for a brief outline of xml namespaces.  Also you may be able to use a newer version of the schema (that one is based on 2001 edition) and see if that works.

Some of the URLs referred to in your WSDL definition return a 404 error.  There is a chance that netmf validates those URLs to return proper xml and fails.

Comment: Have not tested on 4.2 because of hardware contstraint. The framework is 4.1. All schemas are the default from VS both 2008 and 2010. Further research is revealing that this issue might be caused by some of the types listed in the WSDL. For example, I tested returning a DATASET and .netMF will not recognize this type in this 4.1 micro framework. It appears only simple types are allowed, still testing this.

Comment: Yes, DATASET (system.data in general) does not exist in netmf.  The API reference is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee436350.aspx  and shows what classes are available.